# ODOO 10 how to filter delivery orders on the basis of delivery operations line?

Tags: filter, odoo, stock

i am trying to filter those delivery order whose product contain "breakfast".

The domain filter which i am using in action is :

```
<field name="domain">[('pack_operation_product_ids','=','breakfast')]</field>
```

but, it is returning all the records without filtering it.

i want it to filter all records like this, when *all transfer* menu item is clicked.

[image: DNS]
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `search` view add a filter like below.

```xml
<filter string='Product' domain="[('product_id','ilike','braeakfast')]"/>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: it still not working, if using this in search view then its not showing any record (no record found)

Answer (score 0):

if **pack_operation_product_ids** have a relationship like many2many or many2one or one2many then:

Change:

`<field name="domain">[('pack_operation_product_ids','=','breakfast')]</field>`

to like this:

```
<field name="pack_operation_product_ids" widget="many2many_tags" options="{'no_create': True}" domain="[('name','=','breakfast')]"/>
```

Comment: sorry but, i think you got my question wrong. i m looking for domain filter in search view or in "ir.actions.act_window" action record.    ""<field name="pack_operation_product_ids" widget="many2many_tags" options="{'no_create': True}" domain="[('name','=','breakfast')]"/> "" this seems to be a part of form view xml whereas "" <field name="domain">[('pack_operation_product_ids','=','breakfast')]</field> "" this is a part of action record.